# Character encoding-based rules with language without encoding

Tags: discussion, rules, characters

Oftentimes people will ask challenges that have rules hinging on the characters encoded by the source file (see [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)). For example, "Your program may not contain the letter `a`". But some languages are sequences of bytes that are not associated with any character encoding (e.g. machine code or a deflate stream). How should such languages be treated when interpreting this kind of restriction?

Comment: I think the default should simply be ASCII unless the OP says differently. If the source restriction actually affects non-ASCII characters, it will be up to the OP anyway, and having a "default" doesn't really make sense, as it would be unclear from the specification point of view. Just leave it to the OP to provide an explanation of the restrictions.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than propose a default encoding, I'm going to suggest an alternative route: *close the challenge as unclear*.

If it's unclear whether or not `65 66 67` contains `A`, that's the fault of the challenge. Get clarification from the challenge author on what is and isn't allowed.

Comment: From this, it sounds like you're thinking the author should be restricting code *points* rather than representations? "Your source code cannot have 0x66 or 0x88 anywhere" or similar, right?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Exactly. That's unambiguous and doesn't require extra specification for multiple encodings.

Answer (score 2):

I propose that the **Windows-1252** character encoding be used as the default character set for languages that don't specify otherwise.

#### Why Windows-1252?

- By far the most character encodings are ASCII-based (extensions of ASCII-7), so if we were to pick a character encoding, it should be one of those. The sooner we get EBCDIC out of the picture, the better.
- Unicode is the go-to character set in these days, but which encoding? Some byte-sequences are invalid UTF-8, ditto for UTF-16 and UTF-32, so neither of these will fly.
- You could pick the first 256 characters in Unicode and be done with it. This character set already exists, and it's called Latin 1, AKA ISO-8859-1. The downside is, this character set includes a whole bunch of non-printable characters that nobody uses (other than those coming from ASCII).
- So, let's look for a superset of (ISO-8859-1 minus C1 control codes). Wikipedia says that *the* superset of this encoding is Windows-1252. It's also called "ANSI", and while the reason behind it isn't great, the naming certainly did benefit Windows-1252. It still leaves some bytes without an associated character, but there doesn't seem to be a standardized extension that fills them in.

As to why it's named ANSI, i'll let @ais523 explain:

> Microsoft's calling of the encoding "ANSI" is a misunderstanding, rather than anything official. They basically have two sets of APIs, one for Unicode, and one for 8-bit character sets. When originally creating the terminology, they assumed that the 8-bit character sets would be ANSI-standardised, and thus used the name ANSI for them collectively, but it turned out that one of Microsoft's own became much more popular.

- The [comparison of hex editors on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors#Features) also suggests Windows-1252, besides CP437, as a good choice. The hex editor I use personally uses Windows-1252 as well.
- HTML5 standard specifies that Windows-1252 be used whenever a web page says it's in ISO-8859-1. ISO-8859-1 / Windows-1252 is the most common encoding on the Internet after UTF-8, by a wide margin.[<sup>1</sup>](https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/character_encoding)

#### Why any encoding at all?

- It makes displaying the code much easier. Also, it makes character-based source restrictions relevant for the language. Which superset of ASCII is used mostly doesn't matter for the purpose of source restrictions.
- As a case study, the question mentions a deflate stream, but a deflate stream isn't a programming language, so I'll assume you meant Bubblegum, which is a proper superset thereof. But Bubblegum *does* use a charset - it's the same one as is used by the Python 3 interpreter and it becomes relevant when the program's SHA-256 hash is `5e247c455fde7711206ebaa3ad0793114b77a6d16ed0497eff8e3bf98c6dba23`.
- The other language mentioned in the question is machine code (assumed x86). Sure, the instruction parser in a CPU couldn't care less how a byte within an instruction looks when you display it on the screen or which character it represents in ASCII, but there *is* a thing called printable machine code - that is, the subset of machine code restricted to printable ASCII. It becomes relevant when you try to pull off arbitrary code execution on a remote web server.

Comment: I should note that Microsoft's calling of the encoding "ANSI" is a misunderstanding, rather than anything official. They basically have two sets of APIs, one for Unicode, and one for 8-bit character sets. When originally creating the terminology, they assumed that the 8-bit character sets would be ANSI-standardised, and thus used the name ANSI for them collectively, but it turned out that one of Microsoft's own became much more popular.

Comment: @ais523 thanks for the information. Edited.

Comment: I'm just going to throw a Mondrainian wrench into the works. Where does [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) fit, then?

Comment: @draco good point. You could argue that Piet does have a character set defined, though - it's the codels. The character encoding is more unusual than for most languages. Will this argument pass? :-D